# multiple GROUP BY + COUNT display 0 values on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, left-join

I have this query with 2 group by, and I tried to display 0 values.

```
SELECT plan, locale, COUNT( * ) AS res
FROM  domain 
WHERE status LIKE  "active"
AND plan IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY plan, locale
```

I know that I have to do a left join on the same table, but I can't make it works

```
SELECT d1.plan, d1.locale, IFNULL(COUNT(d2.id), 0) AS res
FROM domain AS d1
LEFT JOIN domain AS d2 ON d1.id = d2.id
WHERE d1.plan IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY d1.plan, d1.locale
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Try adding `%` in your WHERE clause, like so:
`WHERE status LIKE "%active%"`

Comment: that's not the issue, it is working well without `%`

Comment: `COUNT(*)` can never be `0`. You either have a group of 1+ rows or you don't have a group. Show some sample data of the table and expected result, otherwise it's not easy to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: maybe you're counting the wrong thing

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `where` clause.  Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT plan, locale,
       sum(case when status LIKE 'active' AND plan IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as res
FROM  domain 
GROUP BY plan, locale;
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT plan, locale,
       sum(case when status LIKE 'active' then 1 else 0 end) as res
FROM  domain 
WHERE plan is not null
GROUP BY plan, locale;
```

Comment: In this case, I could also have in my result PLAN = null. So I need to use a `where` clause